# combine substrings of columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where I want to combine columns as strings but only take the first 3 characters of the respective lines.

Consider `mtcars`: I want to create a column `comb` consisting of the columns `mpg` and `cyl` but only taking the first two characters of `mpg`, separated by`_`.

The desired outcome of the first couple of lines for `comb` is:

```
comb
21_6
21_6
22_4
21_6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `paste` with `substr`:

```
mtcars$comb <- paste(substr(mtcars$mpg, 1, 2), mtcars$cyl, sep="_")
```

If the `cyl` column could contain more than one digit/character, and you only want the first one, then use `substr` a second time:

```
mtcars$comb <- paste(substr(mtcars$mpg, 1, 2), substr(mtcars$cyl, 1, 1), sep="_")
```

Answer (score 1):

with `dplyr`'s `mutate()`, you can use `substr()` and `paste0()` (or `paste(... sep = "_")`, as pointed out above.

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(comb = paste0(substr(as.character(mpg), 1, 2), "_", as.character(cyl)))
```